# Can I get binary data from browser javascript structured clone and then get browser to construct it again?

Tags: javascript

Browsers have a native method of serializing data, and while it might not be as versatile as any method I might implement for my needs, it's guaranteed to be faster (since it's native) and more thoroughly tested.

The [structured clone algorithm](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#structured-clone) is used to with `postMessage` function which is used to transfer data between browser tabs and WebWorkers. But I want to use it in my own data transfer model (e.g. ajax, ending in Node.js). Does browser somehow expose the algorithm so that I can make use of it?

Comment: Your object will still need to be seralised at some point to go between browser and server though - the _actual object_ involved can't be transferred directly, clone or not?

Comment: I thought structured clone algorithm generates the actual serialized data. If not, what does?